# Attaching multiple maven artifacts (built on different physical machines)

Tags: maven

I have a maven plugin which attaches artifacts (zip files containing native binaries) and deploys them.

To be able to distinguish artifacts containing e.g. Windows-binaries from Linux-binaries, the artifacts use a classifier e.g. "Linux-x86_64".

Now, I need to build the different binaries on different machines, and still deploy them to the same server. But what happens is that only the latest deployed set of artifacts are "visible". For example, if I first deploy a set of Linux binaries and then the Windows binaries, only the Windows binaries are available on the server.

On the server, it looks like this:

[image]

I suspect the problem is that each set of artifacts either contains Linux binaries *or* windows binaries, but not both.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are those binaries really being built on the appropriate platform ? Or do they exist already?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The windows-binaries are built on a windows-machine, and the Linux binaries may or may not exist at that time. I would like to be able to upload linux binaries to the repository when/if they have been built.